# createStackNavigator is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am building my first practice app and was trying to put together navigation between screens using the createAppNavigator.

However, as soon as I try to use `createAppNavigator` I get the following error .

[image: error image].

Relevant code:

#### App.js

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Home } from './app/views/Home.js';
import { Contact } from './app/views/Contact.js';
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

const MyRoutes = createStackNavigator({
    HomeRT: { screen: Home },
    ContactRT: { screen: Contact },
  },
  { 
    initialRouteName: 'HomeRT' 
  }
);

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <MyRoutes />
    );
  }
}
```

I am really puzzled as to what I am doing wrong. One idea is that perhaps react-navigation is not installed correctly, but beyond using `npm install --save react-navigation`, I don't know what else I could need to do.

Comment: Oh I remember this type of weirdness.. according to their docs, now they seem to be using `createAppContainer`... So instead of `export default class App`, maybe just do `export default createAppContainer(MyRoutes);`?

Comment: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/hello-react-navigation.html - Follow the documentation here, it's quite explicit, you have to contain the routes class in `createAppContainer`

Comment: if I may make a suggestion, I've tried the navigation quite a few times and had stupid issues with it. It's mostly me being lazy to study docs/nav being weird, but ever since I figured out you can use react router for native, I literally never looked back. https://reacttraining.com/react-router/

Comment: @Sabbin I tried the example code on that website by downloading it and running it locally with expo. Even though it works on snack.expo.io, it gives a similar error to my own app when start the dev server locally

Comment: @PredragBeocanin Thanks for the tip. I will look into react router. So far the use of createAppContainer doesn't seem to change anything

Comment: Yeah, I came from React + I don't like libraries that fail out of the box. Let me look into this, you're running the example code from them with expo? In Android or iOS?

Comment: @PredragBeocanin Huh, well now the tutorial code is working when I run it through expo. Weird. I'm going to try to finagle it to get my practice app working. I'll update here when anything notable happens.. Still frustrated that even though it works I'm not sure what I did differently. If you are still interested I am running it on Android.

Comment: So it's not an answer, but if I create a new expo project and copy/paste my code into it, everything works fine using `export default createAppContainer(MyRoutes);` in place of the section starting with `export default class App extends React.Component {`

Comment: Oh then you solved it using Microsoft approach - if it doesn't work, restart it, lol

Comment: Whenever you use `npm install`, always restart the `react-native run-android`

Answer (score 5):

This can also happen when switching from `@react-navigation/stack` to `@react-navigation/native-stack`, the imported function names differs:

With `/stack`:

```
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
```

With `/native-stack`

```
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
```

If you forget to modify the imported function you will have the same error message.

Answer (score 4):

The`react-navigation` team recently extracted the tab and stack navigators to external repos. You need to do this instead:

```js
import { createStackNavigator } from "react-navigation-stack";
```

You need to install it first, obviously:

```sh
npm i react-navigation-stack @react-native-community/masked-view
```

You will also need to wrap this navigator inside

```js
createAppContainer()
```

Comment: Hi, could you tell me what the error is here: https://snack.expo.io/@tropicalista/bottom-navigation-example

Comment: Whenever I use "react-navigation-stack" as a source of import I get 500 internal server errors. They are unable to resolve module react navigation from "react-navigation-stack"...any suggestions?

Comment: In recent versions (V5 and V6) it should be `import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack'`. You have to install it first, of course.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue then I ran this in the terminal

```
npm install --save @react-native-community/masked-view

import {createAppContainer} from "react-navigation" 
import {createStackNavigator} from "react-navigation-stack"
```

Comment: And why did you run this exactly?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, my solution was to install more older versions of packages.
Versions that I've installed: `@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.14"` and `@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.5"`. It looks like the newest versions have some defects.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33292688)