# I cannot solve the error with my stackNavigator: (0 , _nativeStack.createStackNavigator) is not a function Evaluating App.js Loading App.js

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-navigation

I have a react native project and I receive the following error when I run it with expo:

```
(0 , _nativeStack.createStackNavigator) is not a function
  Evaluating App.js
  Loading App.js
```

I am not sure if this is a dependency issue or another issue with my createStackNavigator but I can't seem to rid of this error. I have tried clearing cache and everything.

[image]

1. App.js

```
       import React from 'react';
   
       import { ThemeProvider } from 'styled-components';
       import { registerRootComponent } from 'expo';
       import { View, Text, Button } from 'react-native';
   
       import { createStackNavigator, createAppContainer } from '@react- 
       navigation/native-stack';
       import { createStore, applyMiddleware, combineReducers } from 'redux';
       import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
       import thunkMiddleware from 'redux-thunk';
       import reducer from './store/reducers';
   
       // Components/screens imported here
      
       const Navigator = createStackNavigator({
       
       Home: { screen: Home },
       RoutineDashboard: { screen: RoutineDashboard },
       Landing: { screen: Landing },
       Profile: { screen: Profile },
       AddAProfile: { screen: AddAProfile },
       AddProfiles: { screen: AddProfiles },
       ProfileInfo: { screen: ProfileInfo },
       Profiles: { screen: Profiles },
       EntryScreen: { screen: EntryScreen },
      
       RoutineDashboard: { screen: RoutineDashboard },
      
   
   });
   
   const App_1 = createAppContainer(Navigator);
   
   export default class App extends React.Component {
       render() {
   
           return (
               <Provider store={store}>
                   <App_1 />
               </Provider>
           )
       }
   }
```

2. Here is my package.json file and dependencies:

   ```
    "dependencies": {
    "react-native-svg": "12.1.1",
    "styled-components": "^5.2.3",
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^12.0.0",
    "firebase/firestore": "8.2.3",
    "react-native-dotenv": "^2.5.5",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.4.0",
    "react-native-elements": "^3.4.1",
    "react-native-firebase": "^5.6.0",
    "react-navigation-stack": "^2.10.4",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.14.3",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.9.3",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^7.1.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^12.0.0",
    "react-circular-progressbar": "^2.0.4",
    "@react-native-firebase/auth": "^12.0.0",
    "react-native-dropdown-picker": "^4.0.9",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~1.10.2",
    "react-native-app-install-date": "^0.1.3",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "*",
    "react-native-circular-progress": "^1.3.7",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "3.2.0",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "0.1.10",
    "react-native-animated-circular-progress": "^1.0.6",
    "react-navigation": "^4.4.4"
    }
   ```

Comment: Why are you using different versions of react navigation? V4, v5, v6 & v2 stick to one version.

Comment: because im a beginner and thats why im having problems

Comment: That is fine use a proper version will solve the issue.  Select the desired version from the top bar https://reactnavigation.org/ and read the docs for that version.

Comment: ok thanks! i will give this a shot. I think this might solve it.

Comment: "react-navigation-stack": "^2.10.4",
 "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.14.3",
 "@react-navigation/native": "^5.9.3",
"@react-navigation/native-stack": "*",
"react-navigation": "^4.4.4"
are these the ones I should be fixing ?

Comment: `react-navigation-*` is old version & `@react-navigation/*` is the latest version

Comment: this worked for me as well as the answer below combined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As aswered on this question: [createStackNavigator is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54428044/createstacknavigator-is-not-a-function)

The `react-navigation` team recently extracted the tab and stack navigators to external repos. You need to do this instead:

```
import { createStackNavigator } from "react-navigation-stack";
```

You need to install it first, obviously:

```
npm i react-navigation-stack @react-native-community/masked-view
```

Comment: I tried this and I am still receiving: "Cannot redefine property: ThemeProvider
  Evaluating react-navigation.js
  Evaluating App.js
  Loading App.js"
Could this be the version issue as mentioned as well?

Comment: this worked for me as well as what was mentioned above regarding removing redundancies in the versions of react-native

Comment: Keep in mind `react-navigation-*` are very old & it is advised to use `@react-navigation/*`